# Gzip .z unix format using c# (deflate algorithm)

Tags: c#, unix, gzip, deflate

For a project we're working on, we need to save a Gzip .z file in C#, in Unix format, using the deflate algorithm.

I've taken a look at GZipStream, but there doesn't seem to be any option to set the file as Unix format. I've also taken a look at Chilkat C# UnixCompress Class, which saves files in Unix format, but it uses the LZW algorithm, not the deflate one.

Anyone knows of a library to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one gzip format.  It is not Unix-specific.  GZipStream produces the gzip format, which can be decoded anywhere.

By the way, the suffix is `.gz`, not `.z`.

I recommend that you *not* use the .NET GZipStream.  Use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead.